# SCALA word count in groups

Tags: regex, scala

```
2018-03-22 04:26:29.0 PM:
Daemon:
Timed Out Connections:
Live Connections:
Live Audio/Video Connections:
SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:7
SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:4
SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:2
SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:6

2018-03-23 08:05:12.0 AM:
Group Dump:
2018-03-23 08:05:42.0 AM:
2018-03-23 08:05:45.0 AM:
SIPB:7827214454065563030@127.0.0.1:3
SIPB:7827214454065563030@127.0.0.1:2
SIPB:7827214454065563030@127.0.0.1:1

2018-03-22 04:34:49.0 PM:
Daemon:
Timed Out Connections:
Live Connections:
Live Audio/Video Connections:
SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:7
SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:4
SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:2
SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:6
```

From the above sample data , i need to count the no of times `SIPB:7827214454065563030@127.0.0.1:3` word has occurred for a particular date which can be grouped under `Live Connections` 
 Also i need to print the date time stamp  of the same group. 
I have the logiC on how to count them in total , but the question is how to count them in groups and print the line that is 3 lines back to string `Live Connections:`
The SIPB group under `Group Dump` is not to be conunted and removed .

Like the resulting o/p should be like this ,

*O/P*

```
2018-03-22 04:26:29.0 PM:
4
2018-03-22 04:34:49.0 PM:
4
```

Code I used to count no of `cat:` in total

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("/home/kafka/Downloads/newdump.txt").getLines().filter(!_.isEmpty()).mkString  
dictionary = Map( """cat:""" -> 1)
val res = dictionary.map { case(k,v) => k -> k.r.findAllIn(lines).size }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @James Whiteley  I added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's meant to be any other info in your real data which might mess with the regex splitting, but this works going off your example data.

First, split the input String into a list of Strings which all begin with a timestamp. Next, for each element in that list you need to find the date and number of instances of `cat:` and output them together.

Fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/LvVDwxR/0

Output:

```
2018-03-22 04:26:29.0 PM:
4
2018-03-22 04:34:49.0 PM:
3
```

---

***EDIT***

The real data contains `SIPB:` and then a bunch of characters, instead of `cats:`. In the below Fiddle is one way you could modify my above code to give the same output with this data.

Fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/92E8wmo/0

Output:

```
2018-03-22 04:26:29.0 PM:
4
2018-03-22 04:34:49.0 PM:
3
```

---

***EDIT 2***

Using the data which Alex has now provided, to only get the examples with Live Connections you just need to filter out the ones which don't:

```
val input =
  """
    |2018-03-22 04:26:29.0 PM:
    |Daemon:
    |Timed Out Connections:
    |Live Connections:
    |Live Audio/Video Connections:
    |SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:7
    |SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:4
    |SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:2
    |SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:6
    |
    |2018-03-23 08:05:12.0 AM:
    |Group Dump:
    |2018-03-23 08:05:42.0 AM:
    |2018-03-23 08:05:45.0 AM:
    |SIPB:7827214454065563030@127.0.0.1:3
    |SIPB:7827214454065563030@127.0.0.1:2
    |SIPB:7827214454065563030@127.0.0.1:1
    |
    |2018-03-22 04:34:49.0 PM:
    |Daemon:
    |Timed Out Connections:
    |Live Connections:
    |Live Audio/Video Connections:
    |SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:7
    |SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:4
    |SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:2
    |SIPB:124340495361123111@127.0.0.1:6
  """.stripMargin

val inputs = input.split("(?=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}[^\\n]*)").map(_.trim)
  .filter(_.nonEmpty).filter(_.contains("Live Connections"))

val output = inputs.map {
  x =>
    val datePattern = "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}[^\\n]*)".r
    val date = (datePattern findAllIn x).toList.distinct.head
    val sipbPattern = "(?=SIPB:[^\\n]*)".r
    val sipbs = (sipbPattern findAllIn x).toList.size
    s"$date\n$sipbs"
}.mkString("\n")
```

Fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/uwU5tSa/0

Output:

```
2018-03-22 04:26:29.0 PM:
4
2018-03-22 04:34:49.0 PM:
4
```

Comment: Hi james , instead of cat my expression contains this string 
`SIPB:6625808001607163030@127.0.0.1:1`
what should be the ideal regex for the same , The digits keep on changing after SIPB:

Comment: You could do this with a positive lookahead, which looks for "SIPB:" and stops at a newline. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Hi james , it doesnt work with the logic you mentioned for SIPB: , like still count is correct but it displays all SIPB:

Comment: this is how the o/p is coming 
    ** 2018-03-23 11:09:46.0 AM:  
    SIPB:0817462793565963030@127.0.0.1:12... **

So ideally the reason is that all SIPB: are coming in front of date in the same line and count is coming in 2nd line 
So to make it work , I need to let the date in the same line and remove all characters till new line .

Comment: Hi Alex, I don’t want to keep going back and editing my answer because I don’t have all the information. I answered based on the info you provided (ie multiple instances of `cat:` over multiple lines). Please amend your question with an example of the exact input and expected output before I try to guess what you are expecting again.

Comment: I don’t mean to come across as rude but I can’t read your mind. I can only answer based on what I’m given and don’t want to spend all day trying to assume I know what you mean.

Comment: Hi james , I edited the question , If you some bandwidth you can try . I tweaked the data so as to simplify for the community . Now added the actual one

Comment: I'll change my answer to match your dataset. If I'm understanding your requirement correctly, you just need to take the list (`inputs` in my example) and do something like filtering out the ones which don't contain the text "Live Connections".

Comment: Edited my answer and put my examples into Scala Fiddles so you can play around with them yourself :) let me know if any parts need clarifying for you.

Comment: Hi James , thanks for responding . See their are two groups of `SIPB:`  One that are having  `Live Audio/Video Connections:` just above them and another group of `SIPB:` which Dont contain Live Audio/Video Connection above them . 
So we need to first search for "Live Audio" And then count the SIPB: below unitl all SIPB: are finished being counted 

    so from the above dataset , I need to first filter the correct group of SIPB and then count them 

Expected o/p : 
2018-03-22 04:26:29.0 PM:
4

Comment: I'll let you figure that one out for yourself ;) you should be able to do it with the techniques used in my answer if you can understand what's been done. Let me know if you need any parts explaining to you. If you're struggling with the Regex, I'd recommend playing around on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: hi james , I do struggle a lot with regex , is there any tool which automatically develops regex for the string i mark , Regex101 looks like a more tester , In which i can test my regex

Comment: That's kind of how you learn. If you look at regex101, there's a "quick reference" section you can look at if you're lost. It'd be more beneficial for you to experiment and find the answer yourself (with the help of a cheat sheet) than for someone to just give you the answer outright. Sites like regex101 and [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_regular_expressions.htm) would be a good place to start :) I don't know of any automatic regex builder. You'd have to look for that yourself.